# Is there a way to prevent URLs from appearing in \bibentry citations?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, tufte

I'm using Tufte document classes, in which citations appear as sidenotes consisting of the full bibliography entry, using (I believe) `\bibentry`. Many of my bibliography entries contain URLs (and I want them there) but I don't want those URLs to appear in the citations.

Is there a way to omit URLs from such citations but keep them in the bibliography?

[image: Example of citation with unwanted URL]

---

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}

\begin{document}

This,\cite{Sarukkai:2005} includes the URL for the citation, which I don't want; thought I do want it in the bibliography.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

---

```
@article{Sarukkai:2005,
author = {Sarukkai, S},
title = {{Revisiting the 'unreasonable effectiveness' of mathematics}},
journal = {Current science},
year = {2005},
url = {http://www.ias.ac.in/currsci/feb102005/415.pdf},
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible by modifying the bst-file.

Copy the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your working folder. I recommand to rename the file maybe something like `MYunsrtnat.bst`. At line 285 of `MYunsrtnat.bst` you find the definition of the url output.

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "URL \url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

Change this definition as follow:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "\urlname{URL} \url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

After this changing you can use the following example. There commands `\urlname` and `\url` gobble their argument. Before the bibliography is printed to commands are set to

```
\renewcommand*{\urlname}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

Here the example:

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@article{Sarukkai:2005,
author = {Sarukkai, S},
title = {{Revisiting the 'unreasonable effectiveness' of mathematics}},
journal = {Current science},
year = {2005},
url = {http://www.ias.ac.in/currsci/feb102005/415.pdf},
}


\end{filecontents}
\providecommand*{\urlname}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\url}[1]{}
\begin{document}
This,\cite{Sarukkai:2005} includes the URL for the citation, which I don't want; thought I do want it in the bibliography.

\renewcommand*{\urlname}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. In the interim I've moved to biblatex. Is there a similar approach I can use there?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Yes. The you have the possiblity `DeclareFieldFormat{url}{}`

Comment: That gets rid of URLs everywhere (as the option url=false would). Is there a way to just exclude them from citations and not the bibliography?

Comment: The same trick. You can also use `AtEveryCite`. But I think it's a new question ;-)

Comment: [Agreed.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46787/7844)

Comment: Where do I find `unsrtnat.bst`?