# Is there a way to prevent URLs from appearing in biblatex citations?

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to customize verbose biblatex citations to exclude URLs (and DOIs) while keeping them in the bibliography. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

While I'm at it, I'd like to get rid of the "In: " that the verbose styles use (in both the bibliography and citations), and put the URLs and DOIs on separate lines in the bibliography.

Comment: Just want to mention that your add-on questions have [already](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/4483) [been](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27953/4483) [addressed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29802/4483). lockstep gives a really nice intro to customizing styles [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/4483).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I answer in order to all your questions

1. Fields in `biblatex` can be deleted by the command `\clearfield`/`\clearlist` (you can consult the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) to find out whether a field is a `field` or a `list`, refer to §2.2.2 *Data Fields*, pp. 15-24). To influence only cite commands you can use the command `\AtEveryCitekey`.

   ```
   \AtEveryCitekey{%
     \clearfield{url}%
     \clearfield{urlyear}
     \clearfield{doi}%
    }
   ```

   Instead you can also use `AtEveryBibitem` for the bibliography.
2. The word "in" can be removed by redefining the macro `in:` as follows:

   ```
    \renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
   ```
3. Extra line breaks can be done by expanding the relevant field formats.

   ```
    \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\newline%
      \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
      \ifhyperref
        {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
        {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
   ```

Every definition can be found in the file [`biblatex.def`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/biblatex.def).

Here the complete code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@article{Sarukkai:2005,
author = {Sarukkai, S},
title = {Revisiting the 'unreasonable effectiveness' of mathematics},
journal = {Current science},
year = {2005},
url = {http://www.ias.ac.in/currsci/feb102005/415.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearfield{url}%
  \clearfield{urlyear}
  \clearfield{doi}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\newline%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{} 

\begin{document}
This, \fullcite{Sarukkai:2005} includes the URL for the citation, which I don't want; thought I do want it in the bibliography.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. This works perfectly, with one glitch. I'm using this code inside of a `\newcommand{mycommand}` definition with arguments, so the `#1` is being substituted with the first argument to `mycommand`, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Use ##1 for this argument

Comment: Nowadays it is better to use `\clearfield` instead of making the field format empty. Making the field format empty will let `biblatex` think it printed the field, when it didn't potentially messing up the punctuation tracker. If I recall correctly, the `\clearfield` commands need to go into `\AtEveryCitekey` and not `\AtEveryCite`, but that should be no hindrance.

Comment: @moewe: You can edit my post.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have switched to using `\clearfield`. If you compare the new output to the old one you will notice that the new one does not feature a full stop at the end.