# How to not display url and visit date in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm doing some slides in beamer, and including the url and visit date in biblatex in a footnote would make it too long. Is there a way to hide these fields?

The citations in the latex file are inserted like this:

```
\footfullcite{some_citation}
```

The following is displayed:

> In: arXiv:xxxx.xxxxx [cs]. Jan. 1, 2000. arXiv: xxxx.xxxxx. url: http://arxiv.org/abs/xxxx.xxxxx (visited on 01/01/2000).

I would like this instead:

> In: arXiv:xxxx.xxxxx [cs]. Jan. 1, 2000. arXiv: xxxx.xxxxx.

Comment: Url and urldate are needed really really really badly if you want to work scientifically and wanna be taken serious. Note though, that you are citing `article`s, not `online` entries.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the advice. I guess I could use `\footcite` and put the full bibliography at the end. But I think there still might be something in between which displays the title and author year in the footnotes.

Comment: Does `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urlyear}}` what you want? See also [Is there a way to prevent URLs from appearing in biblatex citations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46787/35864), [Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864).

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't be using the `@article` entry type for works on arxive that weren't published in a journal, `@online` should be fine. By and large I agree with Johannes_B that URL and url date are necessary, but I would feel fine with leaving out the URL and url date for arXiv entries if you specify the exact version of the paper and the date of publishing.

Comment: @moewe That works, thanks! The works I'm citing are published in conferences so I'm using `inproceedings`, but I still like the arxiv versions since sometimes the conference paper is missing information I'm citing, due to the arxiv version being more frequently updated.